# Golang problem with interface and pointer

Tags: go

I call the function with interface as parameter:

```
myFunction(input) //input type is Image.image
```

and the function body is:

```
func myFunction(input image.Image) {
    if img, ok := input.(interface {
        Set(x, y int, c color.Color)
        Bounds() image.Rectangle
        At(int, int) color.Color
    }); ok {
        //all staff using img.Bounds(), img.Set(), img.Add()
    }
}
```

And it is compiling and works, but I would like to pass the input element by the pointer (because I want to change the input value beyond function also).

I will appreciate any help.

Best,
Bor

Comment: Ensure that the concrete value in `image.Image` is a pointer.  Show the calling code.

Comment: Pass the `&image` where you pass the concrete image to the function.

Comment: in which case the underlying type is not a ptr ? I look at the doc all New functions are returning ptr to something.

Comment: @KeyB0rys Show *how* you want to change the input value "beyond function", or *what* you want to change about the value. Show the input, the way you expect to use "change" it, and the expected result.

Comment: @mkopriva I would like to pass image to myFunction() and call Set() methods to change the image. I would like to change the image which I originally passed to function- not a copy of object.

Comment: @KeyB0rys the dynamic type of the `image.Image`, if it also implements the `Set` method, is already going to be a pointer, you shouldn't need to do anything extra here. If it were not a pointer, the type assertion would fail.

Comment: @KeyB0rys have you even tried calling `Set` on the `img` value? Or is the type assertion failing?

Comment: @mkopriva Unfortunately image.Image does not implement Set method

Comment: @KeyB0rys not all `image.Image` implementations do, which means that there's no way to call `Set` regardless of whether the underlying value is a pointer or non-pointer. Can you show what the dynamic type of the `image.Image` is? You can use `fmt.Printf("%T", input)` to get that. See also this example: https://play.golang.com/p/G1PSyZ8TPkB

Comment: So the input is *image.NRGBA

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213437/discussion-between-mkopriva-and-keyb0rys).